# Native Real Time Communication alternatives to WebRTC

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming, webrtc, p2p

I would like to develop a Real Time Communication (with video and audio) application natively for android and iOS. Ideally it would also be able to connect to a browser however mobile platforms are the most important for this case.

I have been looking into WebRTC, however, as it is a (relatively) new protocol, it seems to not be the best implementation method. It also seems very complicated/frustrating to implement on iOS.

I'm just wondering if anyone else knows of a better alternative to WebRTC that is free and easy to implement natively on iOS and android?

Edit: I have webRTC currently working natively for android however I am still having trouble with native webRTC for iOS. Does anyone have any up-to-date information/tutorials that can help get me started?

Comment: To be honest your question is bugging me, [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499282/what-are-the-realtime-communication-protocols-available-for-the-web) is a list of protocols, unfurtually I couldn't find an easyer way. Anyway, you could do some hard work and do it with socket... (Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116880/stream-live-video-from-phone-to-phone-using-socket-fd) guy, which fall back to "ipcamera".)

Comment: If you still need this functionality, I think there is a detail for everything, you're looking for:[Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, webRTC is the simplest way in order to develop RTC application on mobile and web. As a mobile developer which has no ideo about webrtc, real time communication and voip, you can develop your application without VoIP complexity by using webrtc.

For browser side, webrtc is embedded in Chrome,Firefox and Opera so you should use it directly. Support for IE and Safari can be added via a [plugin](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc4all/). For mobile side, you need to compile webrtc source for iOS and android platforms and then adding webrtc library to your project,you can use it as in browsers. And also webRTC has a simple API, lots of sample and well documentation for iOS and Android. 
These are very explanatory  and helpful tutorials for webRTC on Android in order to understand webrtc flow.

https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Introduction-to-WebRTC-on-Android/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I got it working on android last night but I'm still having trouble figuring it out for iOS. Know of any good tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the crosswalk, you can create a native app using the crosswalk as a webview in your project.

It also works on iOS that is the case

In my case the Web-RTC worked without any problems in the android, but I not tested it  in IOS

Here are some tutorials on how to add the crosswalk on your project.

https://diego.org/2015/01/07/embedding-crosswalk-in-android-studio/

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk.html

I hope this helps.